# is there an easy/efficient way to do multiple lookups in SQL for a value from an ID without multiple joins?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables. One table has an ID column and then other data. Another table has multiple "ID" fields that correspond to the first table. I know I can do multiple joins but each table has 400,000+ records so I thought maybe there is a more efficient way?

Here is an example of what I mean:

This is my lookup table:

```
+----+------+---------+
| ID | Name |  Title  |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | a    | alpha   |
|  2 | b    | bravo   |
|  3 | c    | charlie |
|  4 | d    | delta   |
+----+------+---------+
```

This is my input table. The example only has 2 lookup columns but the production table has 10.

```
+----+------------+------------+
| ID | Lookup ID1 | Lookup ID2 |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |          3 |
|  2 |          2 |          3 |
|  3 |          2 |          4 |
|  4 |          2 |          4 |
|  5 |          2 |          2 |
|  6 |          2 |          2 |
|  7 |          3 |          4 |
|  8 |          1 |          3 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

This is the expected output.

```
+----+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| ID | Lookup Name 1 | Lookup Title 1 | Lookup Name 2 | Lookup Title 2 |
+----+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|  1 | a             | alpha          | c             | charlie        |
|  2 | b             | bravo          | c             | charlie        |
|  3 | b             | bravo          | d             | delta          |
|  4 | b             | bravo          | d             | delta          |
|  5 | b             | bravo          | b             | bravo          |
|  6 | b             | bravo          | b             | bravo          |
|  7 | c             | charlie        | d             | delta          |
|  8 | a             | alpha          | c             | charlie        |
+----+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

I know I can get this using multiple joins (10 in my production environment) but there has to be a more efficient way?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server they have different functions which might be helpful in answering.

Comment: What DBMS is this?  Different answers depending ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do it with a single join, but I wouldn't recommend it. It would involve a complex join condition something like `a.id IN (b.id1, b.id2, ....)` and conditional aggregation; and likely be much much slower than the multi-join equivalent.

It is likely the table structure is just plain poor for your needs (though it is hard to be certain without knowing more details about what is being represented); if you cannot change it, the multi-join is your best solution.

Also, I should note that your assumption that multiple joins would be inefficient is incorrect. "Efficiency" in RDBMS systems is generally more affected by indexing and the ability to use those indexes. One of the reasons `a.id IN (b.id1, b.id2, ....)` is poor is MySQL pretty much ignores indexes when conditions have the equivalent of even a single `OR`.

Answer (score 2):

You do this operation with joins, that's what relational databases do:

```
select i.id, l1.*, l2.*
from input i left join
     lookup l1
     on i.lookupid1 = l1.id left join
     lookup l2
     on i.lookupid2 = l2.id;
```

(The left joins make sure no rows are lost if one of the ids is missing.)

For performance, you want an index on `lookup(id)` or `lookup(id, name)`.  Because `id` should be declared a primary key, another index is not necessary.

Comment: thanks. i was wondering if there was another way to do it without joins but i guess not.